# Como paso una vector a otro vector en posición especifica tipo char C

Tags: array, c

Elabore un programa que lea n cédulas y las coloque en un arreglo usando como índice los dos últimos dígitos del asiento. Determine la cantidad de cédulas que no se pudieron almacenar asumiendo una capacidad de 20.

Ejemplo: "La cédula" 9-752-1211

El indice es 11

La cédula la guardo como tipo char en un vector.

Tengo un segundo vector donde debo guardar en la indice 11 del vector la cédula 9-752-1211

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
main(){
    char cedula[15],indice[5],veccedula[20],u;
    int i,cant,k,a,b,cont;
    printf("Ingrese Cantidad de personas: ");scanf("%i",&cant);
    cont=0;
    for(i=0;i<cant;i++){
        printf("Ingrese cedula#%i: ",i+1);scanf("%s",cedula);
        k=strlen(cedula);
        indice[1]=cedula[k-1];  //ultima posición
        indice[0]=cedula[k-2]; //penultima
        indice[2]='\0'; // fin de cadena
        a=atoi(indice);//Transformo el indice a entero
        if(a<=20){
            veccedula[a]=cedula;
        }
    }
}
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal pero no puedo pasar lo del vector cedula al indice del vector veccedula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto:

```
veccedula[a]=cedula;
```

en realidad lo que hace es **intentar copiar** en `veccedula[a]` **la dirección en memoria de la variable `cedula`**.

Para copiar cadenas **terminadas en `0`**, se utiliza la función `strcpy( )`, de la cabecera `<string.h>`. Dicha función copia **incluido el `0` final**:

```
if( a <= 20 ) {
  strcpy( &( veccedula[a] ), cedula );
}
```

Si no estás seguro de si termina en `0`, o por algún motivo no quieres copiar la cadena entera, sino solamente cierta cantidad de *bytes*, se usaría `strncpy( )`:

```
if( a <= 20 ) {
  strncpy( &( veccedula[a] ), cedula, 2 );
}
```

**Pero** en este caso, `strncpy( )` copiaría **exclusivamente** el número de *bytes* pasados como 3<sup>er</sup> argumento. Si el `0` final no está incluido, tendríamos que ponerlo nosotros *a mano*:

```
if( a <= 20 ) {
  strncpy( &( veccedula[a] ), cedula, 2 );
  veccedula[a+2] = '\x00';
}
```